# Magento Change Product Attribute Set

Tags: magento-1.7

I am adding products from web services for my Magento store.Problem is web services keep changing product attribute set with an interval of few days. I came to know that Attribute Set cannot be changed after a product has been created. So what is the possible way to update the product attribute set? Shall i delete the product and recreate the same product or change the attribute set from database. Which one will be better? If i delete the product will it effect on order/inventory section?

I have already checked by updating attribute set from database.It works fine.For testing purpose I have updated the product which has default attribute set. But i want to update those attribute set that has one custom group containing 10 different attributes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use or analyse code of below free module to change attribute set of a product :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flagbit-change-attribute-set.html

**The code I found from module which can change attribute set :**
This code is located in /app/code/community/Flagbit/ChangeAttributeSet/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/ProductController.php

```
foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
    $product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')
           ->unsetData()
           ->setStoreId($storeId)
           ->load($productId)
           ->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId)
           ->setIsMassupdate(true)
           ->save();
}
```

You should pass below to this code :

- product ids ($productIds)
- store id ($storeId)
- attribute set id ($attributeSetId)

Comment: Will it unset all the Data of particular product? unsetData() what it will do?

Comment: No it will not unset any product data..it will unset object data on which it is called (in this case it is of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product class)

Comment: UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `attribute_set_id` = '9' WHERE `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id` = 15; this one help you.